# Prevent a Latitude/Longitude based chunk system from mercator projection stretching

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, mapbox, map-projections

I'm working on an little mapbox based game and I'm currently working on an lat/lng based chunk system. The distance between each of them should be the same. As you can see in the example the width and height of each chunk are equal. The little grey square is just the chunk middle. Those chunks were created near Latitude/Longitude zero, where they aren't effected by the mercator projection.

[image: Chunks One]

But due to the mercator projection the distances between the chunks are increasing as more as they move away from the middle (they look kinda stretched).

[image: Chunk Two]

As you can see the distances between each one aren't equal anymore. The height of each of those chunks did increase. Heres another picture of the mercator projection to visualize what I mean:

[image]

The chunks of the first picture were created near the middle of the word map (where the big black upper arrow points towards)
The chunks from the second pictures were created near the bottom of the world map, where the other arrow points towards.

The type of game im developing requires equal chunk sizes and also it doesn't look that good, when at some point the chunks look different due to the stretching.

I want to achieve a chunk system like this on the mercator projection:

[image]

I calculate the chunks as follows:

```
First we need the player lat/lng coordinates: 3.0146683, 5.3046076

One latitude is about: 110.57 km -> 110570 meters
One longitude is about: 111.32 km ->111320 meters

One chunk should be about 750 meters on the map.

Because Latitude and Longitude got different ranges we need to adjust the chunk size.

One latitude factor = 110570 / 750 = 147,43
One longitude factor = 111320 / 750 = 148,42

One latitude chunk size = 110570 / 147 = 750 meters
One longitude chunk size = 111320 / 148,42 = 750 meters

(Maybe this step is unnecessary)


Now we convert the Lat/Lng to meters.

Latitude in Meter = 3.0146683 * 110570 meters = 333 331.873931 Meters
Longitude in Meter = 5.3046076* 111320 meters = 590 508.918032 Meters


Now we need to calculate the meters till the last chunk by using modulo.

Latitude Modulo => 333 331.873931 modulo 750 = 331 meter
Longitude Modulo => 590 508.918032 modulo 750 = 258 meter


After that we are able to calculate the Latitude and Longitude chunks.

Latitude chunk position = 333 331.873931 - 331 = 333 000.873931
Longitude chunk position = 590 508.918032 -258 = 590 250.918032


When we divide that now through the chunk size we get the actual chunk position.

Chunk X = 333 000.873931 / 750 = 444,0011
Chunk Y = 590 250.918032 / 750 = 787,001

Rounded: Chunk X = 444 ; Chunk Y = 787


Now we know that the player stands right in this chunk [444;787]

In the next step I just calculate the Chunk X and Y back to latitude and 
longitude and convert them via transform.AsUnityPosition to 3D coordinates, 
where I place those grey objects then.
```

So basically I need a way to have the same visual distance between each of those chunks. Or either a way to change the projection from mercator to a square projection, where nothing is stretched. I never worked with mapbox/googlemaps before...so im a newbie. Or is there maybe a formula I can use to prevent my chunks from being stretched by the mercator projection?

Comment: So does your game use the actual spherical planet Earth as its map? We need to know your strategy for how that sphere should be converted to a flat surface before we can help you implement it. Perhaps you could include another picture that indicates how your chunk map is supposed to look. As I understand it, both latitude and longitude are measured as angles, and longitude especially has no fixed distance associated with it.

Comment: Kyle is correct, as you move further from the equator, the distance between longitudinal lines decreases approaching 0 at the poles.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Nope it doesnt, im just using a flat 2D map from mapbox. But the map projection is still mercator. Mapbox manages the most stuff alone. Im gonna implement one more picture how my chunk system is supposed to look :) Thanks for your comment !

Comment: I think I see what you want to do now. You just want to apply a regular grid to that flat map so that each square is the same size. And you don't care that the distances on that grid aren't going to reflect the actual distances as if you were actually traveling on the actual Earth. Is that correct?

Comment: @KyleDelaney thats totally correct and im glad someone finally understood me ( Was already asking in several other forums ). As you can see i added another picture which represents the grid over the map :D . Nope i dont care about the distance problem, because my game doesnt need exact positions :). Also im doing the movement a bit different ^^.

Comment: If that's the case, you're still sure to run into problems because your calculations mention converting those coordinates to 3D coordinates. Also, I don't understand where your Mercator projection is coming from to begin with. If you have a 2D map of the Earth then it should be a simple matter to divide it into equal pieces. What is happening in your game? Is there a character moving around or are you just clicking a spot on the map? We need to know more about both what you're trying to do and why you're having difficulty doing it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Those coordinates will be converted to 3D coordinates because unity need them. That isnt an problem, it already worked, but the chunks are strechted and the distances between them too, thats the only problem. Theres just a character moving to the position im clicking, thats pretty much all ^^. I cant divide the earth into many equal pieces because i want to use lat lng for that, its necassary. Also mapbox does all the stuff, so i cant modify this directly.

Comment: @KyleDelaney The only problem is that due to the mercator projection the distances between each of my chunks increases. Thats the only problem right now. My calculations are correct i guess. But only correct for a 2D map which isnt stretched. And now i just want to know how i cant modify my equal sized chunk system to make it fit in the mercator projection.

Comment: Okay, so your 2D map remains a 2D map? It's not converted to a sphere, just a plane in 3D space?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Exactly, just a plain and flat 2D map :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160302/discussion-between-kyle-delaney-and-genaray).